# PySerial returning incorrect data from Nova PM SDS011 with raspi3

Tags: python

Here in California, I have purchased some Nova SDS011 PM sensors. When attempting to read from these sensors using Ivan Kalchev's git [repo](https://github.com/ikalchev/py-sds011), I get mixed results. I can send commands to the sensor. e.g. sensor.sleep(sleep=<True/False>) will turn the fan on and off. However attempting to query the sensor to return PM2.5 and PM10 data returns a byte string that does not match the check sum. A couple examples are in the code snip-it below. As you can see, bytes 2 and 6 appear to be corrupt, and furthermore, the response is two bytes shorter than what is expected from the [documentation](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/parts/1/2/2/7/5/Laser_Dust_Sensor_Control_Protocol_V1.3.pdf).

Any Idea whats going on here? Im hoping this is simply a problem with pyserial. I have produced the same results with two sensors.

```
>>> sensor.sleep(sleep=False)
>>> cmd
'\xaa\xb4\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff\x02\xab'
>>> sensor.ser.write(cmd)
19
>>> sensor.ser.readline()
'\xaa\xc0]\x01\xba\x01\xc2*\x05\xab'
>>> sensor.ser.write(cmd)
19
>>> sensor.ser.readline()
'\xaa\xc0c\x01\xbc\x01\xc2*\r\xab'
>>> sensor.ser.write(cmd)
19
>>> sensor.ser.readline()
'\xaa\xc0d\x01\xbf\x01\xc2*\x11\xab'
```

Comment: so I think the *, ], c and d may simply be other bytes...but the checksum doesnt check out....

Answer (score 0):

So this occurred because the python was written for python 3, and my raspberry pi had 2.7. below is the code for 2.7. Thanks to Ivan for putting the original together.

"""This module provides an abstraction for the SDS011 air partuclate densiry sensor.
"""
import struct
import serial

#TODO: Commands against the sensor should read the reply and return success status.

class SDS011(object):
"""Provides method to read from a SDS011 air particlate density sensor
using UART.
"""

```
HEAD = b'\xaa'
TAIL = b'\xab'
CMD_ID = b'\xb4'

# The sent command is a read or a write
READ = b"\x00"
WRITE = b"\x01"

REPORT_MODE_CMD = b"\x02"
ACTIVE = b"\x00"
PASSIVE = b"\x01"

QUERY_CMD = b"\x04"

# The sleep command ID
SLEEP_CMD = b"\x06"
# Sleep and work byte
SLEEP = b"\x00"
WORK = b"\x01"

# The work period command ID
WORK_PERIOD_CMD = b'\x08'

def __init__(self, serial_port, baudrate=9600, timeout=2,
             use_query_mode=True):
    """Initialise and open serial port.
    """
    self.ser = serial.Serial(port=serial_port,
                             baudrate=baudrate,
                             timeout=timeout)
    self.ser.flush()
    self.set_report_mode(active=not use_query_mode)

def _execute(self, cmd_bytes):
    """Writes a byte sequence to the serial.
    """
    self.ser.write(cmd_bytes)

def _get_reply(self):
    """Read reply from device."""
    raw = self.ser.read(size=10)
    data = raw[2:8]
    if len(data) == 0:
        return None
    if (sum(ord(d) for d in data) & 255) != ord(raw[8]):
        return None  #TODO: also check cmd id
    return raw

def cmd_begin(self):
    """Get command header and command ID bytes.
    @rtype: list
    """
    return self.HEAD + self.CMD_ID

def set_report_mode(self, read=False, active=False):
    """Get sleep command. Does not contain checksum and tail.
    @rtype: list
    """
    cmd = self.cmd_begin()
    cmd += (self.REPORT_MODE_CMD
            + (self.READ if read else self.WRITE)
            + (self.ACTIVE if active else self.PASSIVE)
            + b"\x00" * 10)
    cmd = self._finish_cmd(cmd)
    self._execute(cmd)
    self._get_reply()

def query(self):
    """Query the device and read the data.
    @return: Air particulate density in micrograms per cubic meter.
    @rtype: tuple(float, float) -> (PM2.5, PM10)
    """
    cmd = self.cmd_begin()
    cmd += (self.QUERY_CMD
            + b"\x00" * 12)
    cmd = self._finish_cmd(cmd)
    self._execute(cmd)

    raw = self._get_reply()
    if raw is None:
        return None  #TODO:
    data = struct.unpack('<HH', raw[2:6])
    pm25 = data[0] / 10.0
    pm10 = data[1] / 10.0
    return (pm25, pm10)

def sleep(self, read=False, sleep=True):
    """Sleep/Wake up the sensor.
    @param sleep: Whether the device should sleep or work.
    @type sleep: bool
    """
    cmd = self.cmd_begin()
    cmd += (self.SLEEP_CMD
            + (self.READ if read else self.WRITE)
            + (self.SLEEP if sleep else self.WORK)
            + b"\x00" * 10)
    cmd = self._finish_cmd(cmd)
    self._execute(cmd)
    self._get_reply()

def set_work_period(self, read=False, work_time=0):
    """Get work period command. Does not contain checksum and tail.
    @rtype: list
    """
    assert work_time >= 0 and work_time <= 30
    cmd = self.cmd_begin()
    cmd += (self.WORK_PERIOD_CMD
            + (self.READ if read else self.WRITE)
            + bytes([work_time])
            + b"\x00" * 10)
    cmd = self._finish_cmd(cmd)
    self._execute(cmd)
    self._get_reply()

def _finish_cmd(self, cmd, id1=b"\xff", id2=b"\xff"):
    """Add device ID, checksum and tail bytes.
    @rtype: list
    """
    cmd += id1 + id2
    checksum = sum(d for d in bytearray(cmd[2:])) % 256
    cmd += chr(checksum) + self.TAIL
    return cmd

def _process_frame(self, data):
    """Process a SDS011 data frame.
    Byte positions:
        0 - Header
        1 - Command No.
        2,3 - PM2.5 low/high byte
        4,5 - PM10 low/high
        6,7 - ID bytes
        8 - Checksum - sum of bytes 2-7
        9 - Tail
    """
    raw = struct.unpack('<HHxxBBB', data[2:])
    checksum = sum(v for v in bytearray(data[2:8])) % 256
    if checksum != data[8]:
        return None
    pm25 = raw[0] / 10.0
    pm10 = raw[1] / 10.0
    return (pm25, pm10)

def read(self):
    """Read sensor data.
    @return: PM2.5 and PM10 concetration in micrograms per cude meter.
    @rtype: tuple(float, float) - first is PM2.5.
    """
    byte = 0
    while byte != self.HEAD:
        byte = self.ser.read(size=1)
        d = self.ser.read(size=10)
        if d[0:1] == b"\xc0":
            data = self._process_frame(byte + d)
            return data
```